# Ormlite escape special characters in Like query

Tags: android, sqlite, escaping, ormlite

I have next where clause for query in Ormlite:
where.like("name", "%"+constraint+"%")

And if someone will type '%' in search field it will return all results.
There is native Ormlite class SelectArg but it not working in this case.

Is there an easy way to escape all characters for like query with Ormlite?

Thank you!

UPD: Solved this manually with adding escape character details [http://pigtailsoft.com/blog/?p=179 on web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20120528112048/http://pigtailsoft.com/blog/?p=179)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy way to escape all characters for like query with Ormlite?

ORMLite does not have a function to do this.  I'd process the constraint and add a backslash before `'%'`.  Maybe something like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch : constraint.toCharArray()) {
    if (ch == '%') {
        sb.append('\\');
    }
    sb.append(ch);
}
constraint = sb.toString();
```

Comment: It's not working. I did it with raw query using escape character details: http://pigtailsoft.com/blog/?p=179